# Matlab: What's faster? Predefining helpful objects or not?

Tags: matlab, matrix, runtime

I have to do calculations in matlab with very large matrices. I have already made sure to use matrix operations where possible etc. Now trying to fine-tune.
So let A, B, C and D be matrices:

```
C=A*B;
D=cos(C);
```

It seems trivial that the following would be faster (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
D=cos(A*B)
```

My question is if the same it is faster to do if there is more calls of the predefined object:

```
D=f1(A*B) + f2(A*B) + …;
```

instead of predefining C=A*B (which would save a lot of calculations I assume). I have a lot of this kind of expression so some general insight would be useful (at least to know on what kind of parameters i.e. matrix size it depends).

Comment: Seems like something you could easily benchmark yourself. Inlining your code can be faster in some cases (often at the cost of making the code less modular and order to understand), but performance will depend on many things like the sizes of `A` and `B`, and how easy your code can be understood by the JIT compiler. Also, don't [prematurely optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: @Numrok Why should `D=cos(A*B)` be appreciably faster than `C = A * B; D = cos(C)`? I don't understand.

Comment: I thought because you save some the action of saving it into memory. Now that you mention it it seems indeed stupid that this should slow down the calculation significantly. The reason I was thinking about that in the first place is that my program isn't running since apparently my startup disk is too small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From experience I know that changing:

```
y = f1(A*B) + f2(A*B)...
```

to

```
C = A*B;
y = f1(C) + f2(C)...
```

is faster when you have scenarios where you are optimising code - where the operations on the intermediate variable "C" are done multiple times as indicated above.

When the operation is done only once its unlikely to generate a performance improvement, or degradation, as I think the operation is done by Matlab inline before the variable is passed into the function.

To help demonstrate this you can see the benchmark function below which tests both single and multiple operations (3) on variables A & B.

The plot at the bottom shows the results, which are inline with the points above

```
function benchmark

  % test array
  testArray = 100:100:5000;  % 5000 will take quite a while - to test start with smaller (e.g. 500)
  % preallocate
  sep=zeros(numel(testArray),1);
  inline=sep;
  sepcombined = sep;
  inlinecombined = sep;
  fcnSep1    = @() sepfcn;
  fcnInline1 = @() inlinefcn;
  fcnSep2    = @() sepfcn2;
  fcnInline2 = @() inlinefcn2;
  % set up array counter
  count = 1;
  % run throuh all tests
  for i=testArray
    % create A&B
    A = zeros(i,i)+2;
    B = A+1;
    % run single actions
    sep(count)    = timeit (fcnSep1);
    inline(count) = timeit (fcnInline1);
    % combined actions
    sepcombined(count)    = timeit (fcnSep2);
    inlinecombined(count) = timeit (fcnInline2);
    % increment the counter
    count = count + 1;
    % monitor progress
    disp ( i );
  end
  % use nested functions for the actions
  function sepfcn
    C = A*B;
    sum(C);
  end
  function inlinefcn
    sum(A*B);
  end
  function sepfcn2
    C = A*B;
    sum(C)+max(C)+min(C);
  end
  function inlinefcn2
    sum(A*B)+max(A*B)+min(A*B);
  end
  %% plot the results
  figure;
  subplot ( 2, 1, 1 );
  plot ( testArray, sep, 'r-', testArray, inline,'b-' );
  legend ( 'sep', 'inline' )
  title ( 'single action' );
  ylabel ( 'time (s)' )
  xlabel ( 'matrix size' )
  subplot ( 2, 1, 2 );
  plot ( testArray, sepcombined, 'r-', testArray, inlinecombined,'b-' );
  legend ( 'sep', 'inline' )
  title ( 'multiple actions' );
  xlabel ( 'matrix size' )
  ylabel ( 'time (s)' )
end
```

[image]

Comment: And it's good practice to not repeat yourself, thus reducing the change for bugs, improving readability, reducing maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can speed things up by changing code from statements like:

```
D=f1(A*B) + f2(A*B) + …;
```

to statements like:

```
C = A * B;

D=f1(C) + f2(C) + …;
```

because clearly there are fewer multiplies being performed.  I've seen lots of matlab code repeat expressions because the authors are just copy-n-pasting as they go.

At the minimum, there will be less expressions to maintain and debug.  So in general don't repeat yourself.

Comment: Did you test this? Creating the variable `C` takes time and memory. Then there is Matlab's JIT compilation which may well be able to optimise statements like `f1(A*B)+f2(A*B)`... Do you have any proof of these claims? I'd imagine it's not an absolute yes/no.

Comment: @David I'd "guess" as long as there is memory, the precalculation of `A*B` should be faster, And one can always clear `A` and `B` from memory if no further needed.

Comment: @David, no I didn't time it, but the JIT will allocate and use the same memory, there's no way around that.  The stronger argument to do it that way is not repeating expressions, thus reducing the change for bugs, improving readability, reducing maintenance.